# React Router rendering 404 Not Found on reload

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have setup my App.js as below.

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage}/>
        <Route exact path="/location" component={LocationSettings}/>                      
        <Route exact path="/edit" component={Edit}/>
        <Route exact path="/changeName" component={ChangeName}/>
        <Route exact path="/testHtml" component={TestLive}/>
        <Route exact path="/content" component={Content}/>
        <Route component={NotFoundPage}/>
     </Switch>
</Router>
```

And inside the Content component i have the following routes

```
 <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path={`${match.path}`}          component={SideBar}/>
      <Route exact path={`${match.path}/section1`} component={Section1}/>
      <Route exact path={`${match.path}/section2`} component={Section2}/>
      <Route exact path={`${match.path}/section3`} component={Section3}/>
      <Route exact path={`${match.path}/section4`} component={Section4}/>
    </Switch>                   
  </Router>
```

The sections i.e section1, section2, etc are rendered on left sidebar on a small portion. Its working fine until i reload the page after routing to sections. After Reloading, NotFoundPage Component is rendered. But it works correctly on other pages. Is it because of the nesting? What might be the issue??
I am using React-Router 5.1.2

Comment: If you get rid of the inner `Router` component does anything change?

Comment: Try removing the NotFoundPage and read the error react returns. What does it say?

Comment: @ThetAung If i remove the NotFoundPage, Blanck page will be shown instead of NotFoundPage

Comment: @HenryWoody If i remove inner Router component, Sections component will not be rendered and routes to 404 Not found

Comment: Can you provide us with your full code? It seems that this is not enough information to help. You can post it in codesandbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `exact` from the parent `/content` route. What's happening is - when you are on say `/content/section1` and refresh, the route checks commences in parent route and since you have `exact` mentioned, none of the route matches. Therefore the `Content` component itself doesn't render. So none of its child route will be rendered.

**Do this:**

```js
<Route path="/content" component={Content}/>
```

Whenever you have nested routes, make sure that the parent route doesn't have an `exact` route.

Comment: Done. Thank you once again.